# How to Set Order Status to “Processing to Pending” after payment success in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to Set Order Status to “Processing to Pending” after payment success in magento 1.9.3?

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with the `sales_order_place_after` event, this is fired after the call to `$this->_placePayment();` in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::place()` so it should be after any other status changes have happened.

```
$_order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();

$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();

$_order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

// Update order
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementID($orderId);

$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);

$order->save();

// Write your success Massage  here
```

Comment: in which folder put this code?

Comment: i hope you know how to use event and observer. You can put this code in your observer file and this will update status of your order after place order.

Comment: app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Observer.php ?in which line?

Comment: don't edit core. create a custom module and write event and observer in custom module. Editing core is not good practise.

Comment: okay but which line paste this code?

Comment: actually i can't understood how to use this code for update processing to pending payment order?

Comment: Do you know how to write event observer in custom module ?

Comment: no i don't know can you pls help me? how to update processing to pending?

Comment: Otherwise Magento have admin setting also in sales -> payment method , in that also you can set order status after place order.

Comment: then learn event observer first then only i can help you https://webkul.com/blog/observers-in-magento2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52977/discussion-between-pankaj-upadhyay-and-borncoder).

Comment: okay i create Observer.php app\code\local\Order\Update\Model
app\code\local\Order\Update\etc\config.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config> 
<modules> 
<Order_Update> 
<version>0.0.1</version> 
</Order_Update> 
</modules> 
<global> 
<models> 
<Order_Update> 
<class>Order_Update_Model</class> 
</Order_Update> 
</models> 
</global> 
</config>
app\etc\modules\Order_Update.xml
app\code\local\Order\Update\Model\Observer.php 
<?php 
class Order_Update_Model_Observer { 

}
then?